# Some meta tags not added to head when rendered via component

Tags: next.js, meta-tags

I have a `MetaTags.tsx` component that has the following structure;

```
const DEFAULT_IMAGE = {
  url: OgImage, //cloudinary url
  width: '1200',
  height: '630',
};

const MetaTags: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const url = props.url ? `${BASE_URL}${props.url}` : BASE_URL;
  const title = props.title || DEFAULT_TITLE;
  const description = props.description || DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION;
  const image = props.image || DEFAULT_IMAGE;
  const type = props.type || DEFAULT_TYPE;

  return (
    <>
      <meta name="description" content={description} />

      <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />

      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:url" content={url} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
      <meta property="og:type" content={type} />
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Example.com" />
      <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
      <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
      <meta property="og:image:user_generated" content="false" />
      <meta property="og:image" content={image.url} />
      <meta property="og:image:width" content={image.width} />
      <meta property="og:image:height" content={image.height} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MetaTags;
```

Then I import this `MetaTags` component on a page component like so

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import MetaTags from '../head/MetaTags';

const ExamplePage: FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Example Page</title>
        <MetaTags
          title="Example Page"
          url="example-page"
          description="Example Page Description"
        />
      </Head>
    </>
  );
};
```

However, the following meta tags do not get added to the `head` tag

```
<meta property="og:image:user_generated" content="false" />
<meta property="og:image" content={image.url} />
<meta property="og:image:width" content={image.width} />
<meta property="og:image:height" content={image.height} />
```

[image]

Same issue occurs if I add the meta tags directly on the page component inside the `Head` component, instead of using the `MetaTags` component to return the meta tags.

Using version `next@12.0.10`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the value for `DEFAULT_IMAGE`?

Comment: It's a url from cloudinary.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, it is an object. Added it to the code above

Comment: Even if i remove `DEFAULT_IMAGE` and all it's references. i.e `og:image`, `og:image:user_generated` still doesn't get rendered. It does on the page source, but not on the client